# OpenMP - Parallel code give different result from sequential one

Tags: openmp

I got some problem on openmp. I've written some computational codes and parallize the code using openmp. But sequential and parallel gave me different result.

Here is the code

```
for(i=0; i<grid_number; i++)
{
    double norm = 0;
    const double alpha = gsl_vector_get(valpha, i);

    for(j=0; j<n_sim; j++)
    {               
        gsl_matrix_complex *sub_data = gsl_matrix_complex_calloc(n_obs, 1);

        struct cmatrix cm;
        cm.H0 = gsl_matrix_complex_calloc(n_obs-1, nWeight);
        cm.optMatrix = gsl_matrix_complex_calloc(n_obs-1, n_obs-1); 

        for(k=0; k<3; k++)
        {
            gsl_vector_set(sub_b02, k, gsl_matrix_get(b02, j, k));
        }

        for(k=0; k<n_obs; k++)
        {
            const gsl_complex z = gsl_complex_rect(gsl_matrix_get(data2, k, j), 0);
            gsl_matrix_complex_set(sub_data, k, 0, z);
        }

        gsl_vector* theta = gsl_vector_calloc(3);

        c_matrix(sub_b02, sub_data, 1, cm, alpha);                              
        fminsearch(sub_b02, sub_data, cm.optMatrix, cm.H0, theta);  

        gsl_vector_sub(theta, theta1);
        norm += gsl_blas_dnrm2(theta);              

        gsl_matrix_free(sub_data);
        gsl_matrix_free(cm.H0);
        gsl_matrix_free(cm.optMatrix);
        gsl_vector_free(theta);
    }

    double mse = total_weight * norm /(double)n_sim;
    printf("alpha:%f, MSE:%.12e\n", alpha, mse);

    mses[i] = mse;
    alphas[i] = alpha;
}
```

Running this code, give this result:

```
alpha:0.000010, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000076, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000142, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000208, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000274, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000340, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000406, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000472, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000538, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000604, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000670, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000736, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000802, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000868, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000934, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
```

Then I tried to parallize the codes using open mp:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(j,k)
for(i=0; i<grid_number; i++)
{
    double norm = 0;
    const double alpha = gsl_vector_get(valpha, i);     

    for(j=0; j<n_sim; j++)
    {               
        gsl_matrix_complex *sub_data = gsl_matrix_complex_calloc(n_obs, 1);

        struct cmatrix cm;
        cm.H0 = gsl_matrix_complex_calloc(n_obs-1, nWeight);
        cm.optMatrix = gsl_matrix_complex_calloc(n_obs-1, n_obs-1); 

        for(k=0; k<3; k++)
        {
            gsl_vector_set(sub_b02, k, gsl_matrix_get(b02, j, k));
        }

        for(k=0; k<n_obs; k++)
        {
            const gsl_complex z = gsl_complex_rect(gsl_matrix_get(data2, k, j), 0);
            gsl_matrix_complex_set(sub_data, k, 0, z);
        }

        gsl_vector* theta = gsl_vector_calloc(3);

        c_matrix(sub_b02, sub_data, 1, cm, alpha);                              
        fminsearch(sub_b02, sub_data, cm.optMatrix, cm.H0, theta);

        gsl_vector_sub(theta, theta1);          
        norm += gsl_blas_dnrm2(theta);

        gsl_matrix_free(sub_data);
        gsl_matrix_free(cm.H0);
        gsl_matrix_free(cm.optMatrix);  
        gsl_vector_free(theta);
    }

    double mse = total_weight * norm /(double)n_sim;
    printf("alpha:%f, MSE:%.12e\n", alpha, mse);

    mses[i] = mse;
    alphas[i] = alpha;
}
```

And the parallel result:

```
alpha:0.000934, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000802, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000274, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000670, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000010, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000538, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000406, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000142, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000736, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000604, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000208, MSE:1.368388509959e-01
alpha:0.000340, MSE:1.368646778831e-01
alpha:0.000472, MSE:1.369194416804e-01
alpha:0.000868, MSE:1.368691005950e-01
alpha:0.000076, MSE:1.369461873652e-01
```

Why both result is different on some alpha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different results between a sequential and a parallel version of a program virtually always mean one thing: **race conditions**. In your case it is hard to pinpoint the cause because you did not supply a minimal working example (shame on you).

However I have managed to reverse engineer some of what was missing, and I would make the claim that your problem is with the variable `sub_b02`. It is defined outside of the parallel block which makes it shared by default, but you call `gsl_vector_set` on it, which makes different threads write to the same same memory location. Since it is a pointer you will probably have to allocate it inside the `parallel` block.

I can't say that there aren't more things wrong, especially since I can't see into `c_matrix` and `fminsearch`. But what you should do is take a second to think about what variables should be shared/private to threads, then add `default(none)` to the pragma and write out `shared/private` things explicitly. This should give you a better idea of what you're missing.